# How to insert a record into a listview control of asp.net using c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I'm using Visual Web Developer 2008 Express Edition and I need your assistance since I'm new to it. I want to insert a record into my listview control of my asp.net webpage using c# or vb.net codes. Here's how it works, if I have four textboxes and I'm going to fill each textboxes so I click a command button I want to insert the value of each textboxes into the listview control. Please guide on how to do this. Thank you and I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is [Data Binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx), there is a myriad of Exemple to start form, here some exemples

- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/CompleteListView.aspx
- http://geekswithblogs.net/rashid/archive/2007/09/09/Asp.net-ListView---DataBinding.aspx

Update :

Here some vb.net code to help you, I did not test it, it's just to show you the principle.

```
private Class person
  public FirstName as string
  public LastName as string
  public Address as string
end class
```

So you could do something like this in your button Click event

```
Protected Sub Add_Click(ByVal sender As Object, 
                        ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Add.Click
    'create the new object
    dim newPerson as person = new person 
    newPerson.FirstName = FirstNameTextBox.text
    newPerson.LastName = LastNameTextBox.text 
    newPerson.Address  = AddressTextBox.text  

    'Get or create a list
    dim personList As List(Of person) = Session("personList")
    if personList is nothing then
        personList = new List(Of person)
    end if

    'add it to a list and save
    personList.Add(newPerson )
    Session("personList") = personList 

    'Bind the list
    personListView.DataSource = personList 
    personListView.Databind()

end sub
```

Comment: @DavRob--------not necessarily databinding, because when you talk about databinding the record comes from your database. All I want is just to add the records directly from your textboxes into the listview control just like we normally did in windows application. How possible is that?

Comment: IT' long to explain, but in short, one way of doing this is to write a class with the properties you need. then you will be able create a instance of this class, put it in a collection and bind the collection to the list. If you want to add more than one item, you will have to retrieve and save your collection in the session.

Comment: For now its very hard for me to figure it out but if you can provide me a sample code then would be so much better.